# How to create a non modal dialog in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I am trying to create a dialog in material ui which does not blocks the main content.

With my below code i am only able to hide backdrop but not able to disable the backdrop.

```
 <Dialog open={this.state.open}  onClose={this.handleClose} hideBackdrop={true} >
```

Can someone please address my this concern on how to create modals using material-ui which does not blocks the main content

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to post this as a separate answer. The OP was able to solve his problem by disabling pointer events on the root dialog/modal:

```
const StyledDialog = withStyles({ 
  root: { pointerEvents: "none", }, 
  paper: { pointerEvents: "auto" } 
})(props => <Dialog hideBackdrop {...props} />);
```

I also tested the following and it worked as well (should also work with `Modal` component). Note, I also had to use `disableEnforceFocus`, which is a property of the Modal component. You should be aware that there are implications for accessibility when doing this. It's on you to handle the accessibility correctly.

```
<Dialog 
  disableEnforceFocus
  style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
  PaperProps={{ style: { pointerEvents: 'auto' } }}
>
...
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is inherent to modals and `Dialog` is based on [`Modal`](https://material-ui.com/utils/modal/). If you don't want it to block the main content, then one option is to use [Popper](https://material-ui.com/utils/popper/) instead of [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/).

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Cogswell. But i got it working with dialog itself by using the following:

`
const StyledDialog = withStyles({
  root: {
    pointerEvents: "none",
  },
  paper: {
    pointerEvents: "auto"
  }
})(props => <Dialog hideBackdrop {...props} />);

`